# Build a PDF from a template

Tags: c#, excel, pdf, ms-word

I have a SQL Server table as my data source and I want to export the rows into a PDF document. I have defined a template in Word or Excel:

[image]

Each row of the SQL Server table should be a PDF Page. Do you know a good approach to get it? I thought, I can use the OpenOffice libraries and for each row, I can duplicate the template page, fill the data of the row and at the end I can convert the final document in PDF.

Another approach could be having a pdf template and fill the data directly into the pdf.

Do you know an easier approach to get it? Using ITextSharp could be quite difficult and in this context is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PDFStamper to write your data into a PDF template.
Just place some placeholder fields to a PDF Template.

```
  string pdfTemplate = "C:\\Temp\\Template.pdf";
  string newFile = "C:\\Temp\\TemplateFilled.pdf";


  //create a new PDF reader based on the PDF template document
  PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfTemplate);


    // add content to existing PDF document with PdfStamper 
    PdfStamper formFiller = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(newFile, FileMode.Create));

    if (formFiller == null)
    {
      return false;
    }

    AcroFields formFields = formFiller.AcroFields;

    formFields.SetField("Field1", sqlfield1);    
    formFields.SetField("Field2", sqlfield2);

    formFiller.Close();

    return true;
```

Bye Nu